# Can one keep chocolate uncovered in the freezer?

Tags: freezing, chocolate

I bought a chocolate bar and only hate half of it. I want to store it in the freezer, but part of it will be uncovered. Is this a safe way to store it in the freezer ?

Comment: How long will you store it in the freezer? Why do you want to store it in the freezer?

Comment: @AMtwo I will probably store for 2-3 days.

Comment: What kind of chocolate bar? Pure chocolate (milk or dark) or something more like a Snickers bar?

Comment: Why do you want to store it in the freezer?

Comment: Its a dark chocolate bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Food-safety-wise, putting chocolate in the freezer is not an issue and not even necessary.

However, quality may suffer:

- Freezers do tend to have some off flavors over the time, and these can be absorbed by the food inside, if not packaged properly. To be safe, I recommend you put the chocolate bar in some kind of airtight package, either a freezer bag or a Tupperware-style box.
- Humidity can be a problem for “crisp” fillings like wafers or, to a lesser extent, crispy caramel. The packaging and the chocolate coating protects the original bar, once you have eaten half, it is exposed. Unless you live in an exceptionally humid environment or store too long or in a humid environment where condensation can happen - like a freezer - , this should be a minor issue. Again, wrapping the half-eaten bar with a (mostly) airtight seal should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend freezing chocolate. It can cause the chocolate to crystalize. I'd put it in the fridge tightly wrapped and sealed. If you've bitten it directly you can just cut off a centimeter and pop that in your mouth first. Unless your house is particularly warm and humid a chocolate bar will be fine stored at room temperature. If it is not pure chocolate (e.g. a candy bar with nougat) and some of the ingredients may spoil in the air, then putting in the fridge is your best bet.